# Can't sample grease pencil color with a hotkey

Tags: grease-pencil

For some reason, pressing S doesn't sample grease pencil stroke color in vertex mode. I can still do it through the color wheel though. Keymaps look fine. I'm using blender 2.93.1

[image]